# Probability of needing $N$ uniform samples to have a sum of 2 or more

Tags: probability

Suppose that I sample $x_i$ from a uniform distribution, i.e., $x_i \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$, starting at $i=1$. I stop doing that at $i=N$, such that the sum passed $2$. Then we have:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} x_i &< 2, \\
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i &\geq 2.
\end{align}

Here, $N$ is a random variable as it depends on the random samples $x_i$. I would like to know if there is an expression for the probability $P(N=n)$ for any integer $n$.

I tried this for $P(N=3)$. Then we have $x_1+x_2+x_3\geq 2$ and $x_1+x_2\geq 1$, so I evaluated the integral 
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{1-x_1}^1 \int_{2-x_1-x_2}^1 \mathrm{d}x_3\mathrm{d}x_2\mathrm{d}x_1 = \frac{1}{6}.
$$
However, this seems very cumbersome, especially when $n>3$, so I hope there is an easier way to do this. I also wrote a simple script to calculate $P(N=n)$. From this, it seems that $P(N=4)=\frac{1}{3}$, but for $P(N=5)$ is do not easily see a rational number...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $n>2$. Notice that if $x_n>0$, then it is possible for the rest of variable to have sum at least $2-x_n$ but not more than $2$. As a consequence,
$$
\mathbb P(N = n) = \int_0^1 \mathbb P(2>x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{n-1} >2-x) dx 
$$
The sum of $k$ uniform independent variables on $(0,1)$ follows the [Irwin-Hall Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), so we can substitute its cdf inside the formula with $k=n-1$
$$
\mathbb P(N = n) = \frac 1{(n-1)!}\int_0^1 
\left[
\sum_{k=0}^{2}(-1)^k {{n-1}\choose {k}} (2-k)^{n-1} -
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor 2-x \rfloor}(-1)^k {{n-1}\choose {k}} (2-x-k)^{n-1}
\right]
 dx \\
=
\frac 1{(n-1)!}\int_0^1 
 2^{n-1}
-(n-1) 
 -
(2-x)^{n-1}
+ (n-1) (1-x)^{n-1}
\, dx\\
=
\frac  {2^{n-1}-(n-1)+1/n -2^n/n + (n-1)/n}
{(n-1)!} 
=
\frac  {(n-2)(2^{n-1}-n)  }
{n!} 
$$
Notice that for $n=3,4$ it is exactly $1/6$ and $1/3$.

Comment: Nice solution! The Irwin-Hall Distribution is new to me :). Thanks!